# CYGWIN + ORA*C = PCC-F-NOERRFILE, unable to open error message file, facility PR2

Tags: c, oracle, netbeans, cygwin

I am having some issues with ORA*C and Cygwin.

I am trying to port this UNIX program into Windows using Cygwin.

I installed Cygwin with all the C libraries,etc.

And I also installed Oracle 10g (reason being that UNIX project is currently using that and I want to keep things 100% compatible).

If I open cmd and type `proc myfile.pc etc etc` It runs pretty well.

When I try to do the same thing in Cygwin terminal (or Netbeans) I get the following error:

```
PCC-F-NOERRFILE, unable to open error message file, facility PR2
```

I read somewhere in google that this has to do with the ORACLE_HOME environment variable, I tried setting this variable to:

```
/cygdrive/c/Oracle/product/10.2.0/client_1
```

or

```
C:\Oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1
```

in the windows path settings and/or my Makefile and I am still having the same issue.

Any insights?

Comment: Does your ORACLE_HOME contains a precomp directory?

Comment: The configuration is not supported.

Comment: Steve
do you mean that pro*c is not working with Cygwin?